# Minimizing Python Modules

Tags: python

Suppose that I have a python module A in my libraries directory. How can I export the same library as module B, however use only the functions and the code parts I need automatically? For instance, I want to build a minimal version of openCV for Python for a laser tracking project and I am sure that the code I actually need is much less than the whole openCV library. I don't want to do this by hand, so is there any kind of application that automates this proceedure?

Comment: Is your problem disk space related? Because otherwise I don't really see why you'd like to do this: the modules you're not using will not slow your code down (perhaps the setup, but that's only once).

Comment: Yes. It is my android phone

Comment: Since reducing disk space is the motivating factor, an alternative approach might be to put the (entire) module or modules in a zip file -- see [zipimport — Import modules from Zip archives](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipimport.html) in the docs.

Comment: The only thing I neer in this case are threshold and rgb splitting functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: I saw the comments and noted you are struggling with a space issue. In that case the code below is not what you are looking for. I think you will have to write the minimized version of the target module. Otherwise you will have to implement some kind of tool that enables you to find all dependences of functions you want to use automatically.

You have to choose if it's worth the effort.

```
class Importer:
    def __init__(self, module_name, funcion_list):
        self.__module = __import__(module_name)
        self.__specific = funcion_list

        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        for elem in self.__specific:
            setattr(self, elem, getattr(self.__module, elem))
```

Lets say you want only export the function `listdir` from module `os`. So, in your `B` module you can:

```
os_minimized = Importer("os", ("listdir",))
```

And then in other module you write:

```
from B import os_minimized
print(os_minimized.listdir("."))
```

Comment: And how can I export it to a new python module file? UPDATE: I have forgotten to refresh this page. However can anyone help me with this?